# NewRelic support for Java apps on AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, newrelic

I'm part of an engineering team that develops Java web APIs and deploys them into AWS. For the past ~2 years we've used Elastic Beanstalk, but now we're trying to migrate to Lambda for the cost savings and operational simplicity. Unfortunately, we rely heavily on NewRelic monitoring today and I have a strong feeling - though I haven't found a definitive answer one way or the other - that NewRelic doesn't play well with Lambda (specifically for Java applications).

Surely others have run into this problem. What's the current state of NewRelic + AWS Lambda interaction? For starters, I don't see a way to provide the custom NewRelic javaagent to the JVM in Lambda. As a possible workaround for NewRelic Insights, I could send data from my Lambdas to a dedicated EC2 server running NewRelic, and publish it from there... but then I'd still lose NewRelic APM on my Lambda services.

Answer (score 2):

There are no exposed APIs for Lambda at the time of this writing. The only things you can do from the code level is sending log and telemetry data from the app to a service (New Relic or otherwise). The issue is that Relic doesn't really do events or logs the best way. There are other services available such as the company I work for AppDynamics or various others. These are platform agnostic.

Finally most APM products (New Relic and AppDynamics) have a pretty sophisticated Java SDK for instrumenting within your code. This means you can embed the agent code within your code which should work on Lambda, I haven't tried this yet:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/plugins/developing-plugins/writing-code/using-java-sdk

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Add+Custom+Fields+to+Transactions+Using+Java+SDK